# How to alter a cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

I want to store a string in a cookie of the form

```
 1.236|2.48|3.574|4.094|
```

Each number 1-4 correlates to a div and the number after the dot correlates to a property of the div.

What I want to do is for php to examine the cookie and see if there is an entry for div 3 and if there is, remove the number after the dot and replace it by a number I supply and if not, create an entry in the string with the number I supply. So if the string in the cookie was of the form

```
 1.236|2.48|4.094|
```

Then the php would set it to

```
 1.236|2.48|4.094|3.66|
```

with 66 being the number supplied by the script.

And if the string in the cookie was of the form

```
 1.236|2.48|3.574|4.094|
```

then the php would set it to

```
 1.236|2.48|3.66|4.094|
```

(or just as good would be:

```
 1.236|2.48|4.094|3.66
```

)

I have used dots and '|' in my example but they are just as placeholders to separate the data, if they can't be used in a cookie then any other random fixed symbol should do.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cookieName = 'myCookie';
$newValue = 66;
$newString = preg_replace('/3\.[0-9]+/',"3.$newValue",$_COOKIE[$cookieName]);
if (strpos($newString,'3.'.$newValue) === false) {
    $newString .= '3.'.$newValue;
}
setcookie($cookieName,$newString);
```

Comment: That is neat. I spent some time looking up what that means and it does exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `setcookie()` function (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)) to set and `$_COOKIE` array (see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)) to read cookies.

Comment: As far as I can see I am not setting a cookie, I am modifying an existing cookie. I know how to create a new cookie but I want to modify the contents of a cookie here.

Comment: as soon as you set the cookie, you modify it

Comment: @James there is no "modify a cookie". To modify one, you read the cookie's contents, make your changes, and then re-set the cookie with the new value.

Comment: @James Sascha is right - if you set the same cookie again, it is like modifying it. As I said: use `$_COOKIE` to read and `setcookie()` to set (modify) it.

Comment: @Marc Correct - to do what James understands by 'modifying', you have to set the cookie again.

Comment: Oh I see. So setting a new cookie with the same name as the old one but with updated value would overwrite my existing cookie?

Comment: I see extra comments have appeared above, I get it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @james. it'd be the equivalent of doing `$x = 7; $x = 8;` in code. You don't "modify" `$x`, you just overwrite it with a new value.